# Getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of null in js

Tags: javascript, html

I have this jquery code that goes through the nav bar and the selected link has a box around it. It only works on the middle link, none of the others. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
navigation arrow starts
var $el, leftPos, newWidth,
    $mainNav = $("#nav");

$mainNav.append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");
var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");

$magicLine
    .width($(".current_page_item").width())
    .css("left", $(".current_page_item a").position().left)
    .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
    .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

//scroll arrow

function update_location(){
    $el = $('#nav').children('li.current');
    leftPos = $el.position().left;
    newWidth = $el.width();
    $('#nav li:nth-child(4) a').addClass('button-style');
    if(window.top.scrollY == 0)
    {
        setTimeout(function(){
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: 8,
            width: 355
        });},1000);
        $('#nav li:nth-child(4) a').removeClass('button-style');

    }
    else
    {
        setTimeout(function(){
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: leftPos,
            width: newWidth
        });},1000);
    }
}

$('#magic-line').css('left', '-15px', 'width','411px');
$(window).scroll(function(){
    update_location();
});

    <div class="navbar-fixed-top navbar" >
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right" id="nav">
                <li class="current_page_item" style="width: 355px;"><a href="#home" class="logo" style="display:block; width: 355px;"><img src="images/logo.jpg" class="current_page_item" width="355" alt="" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#vision">VISION</a></li>
                <li><a href="#services">SCHOOLS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#apply">REQUEST AN EVALUATION</a></li>
                <li><a href="#how-it-works">HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact-us">CONTACT US</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Getting the error after `leftPos = $el.position().left;` under `function update_location()`

Comment: The problem is that `$el = $('#nav').children('li.current');` contains zero elements. Hence, `.position()` is `null`, and your error is observed. Another note: **Ever heard about variable declarations**? When all `var` prefixes is omitted, the variables are defined in the global scope.

Comment: I understand it's null, but why is it null?

Comment: Because that's defined behaviour in [`jQuery.fn.position` (source)](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.fn.position): `if (!this[0]){return null;}` - When there's no element, `null` is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be meaning to use the class current_page_item instead of current on this line:

```
$el = $('#nav').children('li.current');
```

$el is an empty jQuery object so el.position() is null and hence, cannot read property left of null.

Comment: I replaced current with current_page_item and still hasn't changed. The error is gone though.

Comment: It seems like when it loops through, it only assigns 'button-style' to the middle link and never takes it off and assigns to another link.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because:

```
$el = $('#nav').children('li.current');
```

returns null.

Try:

```
$el = $('#nav').children('li.current_page_item');
```